# class TC_JOIN (NAME) {}

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

I found the following code [here](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/blob/master/src/Volume/Cipher.h):

```cpp
class Cipher {
...
};

#define TC_TRIAL(NAME, BLOCK_SIZE, KEY_SIZE) \
class TC_JOIN (Cipher,NAME) : public Cipher  { \
...\
}

TC_CIPHER (AES, 16, 32);
```

I am aware that this is a macro and that `(NAME, BLOCK_SIZE, KEY_SIZE)` are additional parameters, but after the preprocessor replaces any corresponding occurrences of the parameters in the replacement list, we should get something like this, I gather:

```cpp
class TC_JOIN (Cipher,AES) : public Cipher  {
...
}
```

The `TC_JOIN (Cipher,AES)` slightly baffles me (especially the addition of the parentheses part). Would you be so kind as to explain to me what exactly this syntactic structure is supposed to mean?

Comment: The answer lies in what `TC_JOIN` is, which is almost certainly another macro that concatenates tokens. The result is likely `class CipherAES : public Cipher {...` or similar. Please [edit] your post to include the definition of `TC_JOIN` in order to be sure.

Comment: It just invokes another macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TC_JOIN` is defined in [VeraCrypt/src/Platform/PlatformBase.h](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/blob/32976931ee0b1457b032243683c0699dbd92d496/src/Platform/PlatformBase.h):

```
#define TC_JOIN_ARGS(a,b) a##b
#define TC_JOIN(a,b) TC_JOIN_ARGS(a,b)
```

It concatenates the two parameter.

When you are not sure what a symbol means, then search for its definition. I saw that `Cipher.h` (the header you quote from) includes `Crypto/config.h` and `Platform/Platform.h`. When I realized that `Platform.h` is a header that merely includes loads of other headers I gave up on that route and used the github search to find all occurences of `TC_JOIN`. One of them was `#define TC_JOIN ...`. There you go.